# txt into pandas dataframe deleting some lines first

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt file with some data I want to save in a pandas data frame. The txt file looks like this

```
##fileformat=VCFv4.1
##FORMAT=<ID=GQX,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Minimum of {Genotype quality assuming variant position,Genotype quality assuming non-variant position}">
##FORMAT=<ID=GT,Number=1,Type=String,Description="Genotype">
##FORMAT=<ID=GQ,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Genotype Quality">
##FORMAT=<ID=AD,Number=.,Type=Integer,Description="Allele Depth">
##FORMAT=<ID=VF,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="Variant Frequency">
##FORMAT=<ID=NL,Number=1,Type=Integer,Description="Applied BaseCall Noise Level">
##FORMAT=<ID=SB,Number=1,Type=Float,Description="StrandBias Score">
##INFO=<ID=TI,Number=.,Type=String,Description="Transcript ID">
##INFO=<ID=GI,Number=.,Type=String,Description="Gene ID">
#CHROM  POS ID  REF ALT QUAL    FILTER  INFO    FORMAT  sample_name
chr1    36933574    .   T   G   66.00   SB  DP=1110;TI=NM_172313,NM_156039,NM_000760;GI=CSF3R,CSF3R,CSF3R;FC=Silent,Silent,Silent   GT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX   0/1:66:1071,32:0.0288:20:-0.0001:66
chr1    115256530   .   G   A   23.00   SB  DP=1707;TI=NM_002524;GI=NRAS;FC=Nonsense_Q61X;EXON  GT:GQ:AD:VF:NL:SB:GQX   0/1:23:1678,29:0.0170:20:0.0000:23
```

I need to delete the lines starting with ## and then store the following data in a pandas dataframe.

What is the best way to do that. I have used this

I have tried this:

```
Name_file1 = "File_name"
# Remove the header of input files

cmd = "sed '/^##/ d'  {0} >  FileA.txt".format(Name_file1)
os.system(cmd)

# Files to pandas object
dataA = pd.read_csv("./FileA.txt", delimiter = "\t" )
```

But this is not going to work in Windows.

And now this:

```
Name_file1 = "File_name"

with open(Name_file1, 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

But I don't know how to transform the variable in a pandas data frame

Answer (score 0):

Don't modify you file, just tell pandas that there are comments:

```
pd.read_csv('filename', comment='#', delimiter='\t')
```

To get the column names:

```
columns = ['CHROM ', 'POS', 'ID', 'REF', 'ALT', 'QUAL', 'FILTER', 'INFO', 'FORMAT', 'sample_name']
pd.read_csv('filename', comment='#', delimiter='\t', names=columns)
```

If the column names are not always the same for various files, use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('vcf_file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('#') and len(line)>2 and line[1] != '#':
            columns = line[1:-1].split('\t')
            break
df = pd.read_csv('vcf_file', comment='#', delimiter='\t', names=columns)
```

*NB. There are also specialized libraries to read vcf files, such as [pyvcf](https://pyvcf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)*

Comment: As  simple as perfect! Thanks

Comment: How can I get the names of the column that are in line #. As this is a script that run with many files, I cannot introduce manually the names and I really need the sample name in the code below

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoPalacios I added a small snippet for that. Also, if you work with vcf files, you might be interested in [pyvcf](https://pyvcf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)